# Jquery Validate submitHandler

Tags: validation, button, submit

I've tried searching both this forum and the web looking for an answer, but if there are any at all they just tell me to do what I've already tried.

So, my problem is this: I've got a form that runs through two validators, one client side jquery and one server side php (gravity forms). This has been working great for some time now. However, we've noticed that we get a lot of duplicates of submissions, so I want to disable the submit button, once the form has been validated on the client side. When the form has been filled and submitted, it runs the client side validation script, if the fields are valid - disable the submit button (to prevent double submissions) - and send the script to the second validation. If any of the fields are invalid, the validation should return an error message and NOT disable the submit button.

I had a look around and finally added this:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
$(form).find(":submit").attr("disabled", true).attr("value",
"Submitting...");
form.submit();
}
```

to the end of my validation script.

This, however, did not turn out as I had hoped. I've tried all kinds of different variants of the above, but when I add it, the script won't run at all or it just disables the submit button (even though all of the form fields are invalid), which makes it impossible to correct and resubmit - you hade to reload the page to enable the submit button again.

What am I doing wrong? The whole validation script looks like this:

```
jQuery(function() {


var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#gform_6').validate( {     
rules       : {
input_6      : { required: true, personnummer: true },          // Personnummer
input_30     : { required: true, personnummer: true },          // Personnummer
input_10     : { required: true, minlength: 6 },                 // telenr
"input_21.1" : { required: true },                               // villkor
"input_3.3"  : { required: function(element) { return (jQuery(element).parent().is(":hidden") == false); } },  // 
"input_3.6"  : { required: function(element) { return (jQuery(element).parent().is(":hidden") == false); } },  // efternamn
input_7      : { required: function(element) { return (jQuery(element).parent().is(":hidden") == false); }, email: true },  // e-post 1
input_31     : { required: function(element) { return (jQuery(element).parent().is(":hidden") == false); }, email: true, equalTo: "#input_6_7" }, // e-post 2 //adress       : { required: true },  // adress
input_14     : { required: function(element) { return (jQuery(element).parent().is(":hidden") == false); } },   // lön
input_15     : { required: function(element) { return (jQuery(element).parent().is(":hidden") == false); }, number: true, minlength: 4, maxlength: 5 }, // clearingnr
input_16     : { required: function(element) { return (jQuery(element).parent().is(":hidden") == false); }, number: true, minlength: 7 }    // kontonr
      },

messages    : {
//pnummer      : "Födelsedatum ogiltigt, ska ha formatet 19770131-1234",
input_6      : "",
input_30     : "Födelsedatum ogiltigt, ska ha formatet 19770131-1234",
"input_3.3"  : "Du måste fylla i ditt förnamn",
"input_3.6"  : "Du måste fylla i ditt efternamn",
input_7      : "Ej giltig e-postadress",
input_31     : "Dina mail-adresser stämmer ej överens",
//adress       : "Fyll i din adress",
input_14     : "Fyll i din lön",
input_10     : "Fyll i ditt telefonnummer",
input_15     : "Clearingnummer måste vara 4 eller 5 siffror",
input_16     : "Kontonummer måste vara minst 7 siffror",
"input_21.1" : "Du måste acceptera villkoren"
},


//debug        : true,

errorClass   : "form-error",
errorElement : "span"
//validClass   : "valid",
submitHandler: function(form) {
$(form).find(":submit").attr("disabled", true).attr("value",
"Submitting...");
form.submit();
}


}
);
```

Please

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're doing something wrong with you validation code. The problem is more on the submission of your form. Why don't you validate it before you effectively submit your form? Like this:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
//Validates your form
$(form).validate();
//Checks if the form rules are all valid
if($(form).valid()){
$(form).find(":submit").attr("disabled", true).attr("value",
"Submitting...");
form.submit();
}
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a var to check if there were a submission on your form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isSubmit = false;

$(form).submit(function(){
//Checks if the form has already been submitted
if(isSubmit === false){
isSubmit = true;
//Do your form submission logic here
}
//Just in case you don't want it to conclude
return false;
});

</script>
```